# Is it possible to format a number to 2 decimal places with Smarty PHP

Tags: php, smarty

Is it possible to format a number to 2 decimal places with Smarty PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[string_format](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.string.format.php) accepts sprintf formatting options:

```
{$number|string_format:"%.2f"}
```

Comment: This does not work with numbers containing less than 2 decimal places.  (ie. 1.9)

Comment: Yes it does. It turns `1.5` into `1.50`.

Comment: Remember that if you want to place an expression in place of  the plain variable `$number`, you should wrap them into parenthesis, like: `{($a/$b)|string_format:"%.2f"}`

Comment: Hi. Is there any way for this filter to work like this with one exception. In case the number is integer to display it like that? Meaning if the number is 2, display 2 instead of 2.00 ?

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got an error about the modifier not existing. Is it only certain versions of Smarty perhaps?

Answer (score 30):

`{$number|number_format:2}` is what you want

Comment: Remember that if you want to place an expression in place of  the plain variable `$number`, you should wrap them into parenthesis, like: `{($a/$b)|number_format:2}`

Comment: This didn't work for me, it formatted the number with zero decimal places ignoring the parameter.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the round function, though it will not add decimal places only remove them:

`{$number|round:2}`

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as it is dealing with numbers rounding and treating numbers as numbers instead of strings.

Comment: Remember that if you want to place an expression in place of  the plain variable `$number`, you should wrap them into parenthesis, like: `{($a/$b)|round:2}`. Quotes around `2` aren't mandatory

Comment: Does not change 123 to 123.00

Comment: This does rounding but doesn't format a number to 2 decimal places as the OP asked. (It doesn't add zeros to the end when necessary.) And `string_format` seems to round sometimes and not others. This does both: `{$number|round:"2"|string_format:"%.2f"}`

Comment: This was the only answer that actually worked on the version of Smarty I'm running... and it did round to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score -3):

To display 2 instead of 2.00 you can use : **replace** in Smarty PHP

See below example -

```
$number = 2.00

{$number|replace:'.00':''}

Output :- 2
```

Hope this helps.