# Number formats in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, number-formatting

How to display my price (`200000 into 2 Lacs, 20000000 => 2 Crore`)as decimal value in smarty

I stored price value as

```
200000
350000
2000000
20000000
```

in MySQL now i need to display this value as

```
2/2.00 Lacs 
3.5 lacs 
20/20.00 lacs
2/2.00 crore
```

Possible duplicate question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409110/is-it-possible-to-format-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-with-smarty-php)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Rob Agar.

I'm not sure on the figures you have, but something like this for a custom modifier is a starting point

```
function smarty_modifier_indian_currency($price)
{
    if($price>100000)
    {
        $lacs=$price/100000;
        // lacs

        if($lacs<100) return $lacs.' lacs';

        $crore=floor($lacs/100);
        $lacs=$lacs-($crore*100);

        if($lacs==0) return $crore.' crore';
        return $crore.'/'.$lacs.' crore';

    }
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky bit is handling Indian currency formatting, which is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php). After that it's straightforward to add a [custom Smarty modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) to allow you to write something like this in your template:

```
{$amount|format_indian_currency}
```